# Custom(ize) Drupal search block

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to either customize the current Drupal search block or create a new search block to display a search field below the main navigation. See below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU5Ia.png

The search blocks needs to work like this: 1) click the icon to open the search field, 2) type in your search term, and 3) hit enter or the second icon in the field to run the search function (like the default operation).

Would it be possible to either: a) recode the current search block to function like in the image, or b) code a new search block that works this way?

The default search value needs to be translatable.

Comment: Well, you can do it both ways if you want to, but I think there's no use to create a new block with search form, since it's already there. Most of the work you need to do is javascript and css. I think you don't have to use php at all in this case. First, hide the form with CSS then add new js file which will display the form on icon click. That's all about js, hitting enter works by default, icon can be added by CSS, default "Search" text might be hidden in CSS or you can override the form, but this will need some php work.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your comment. I am looking for quite specific instructions and/or code to implement this. I am not an adept Drupal developer, so I would ask that you elaborate further on your ideas if possible? If the default search block is the way to go, using that as an example, how would one approach turning it into something like the image I designed?

Comment: I can't give you specific instructions because it depends on the theme structure, but if you're familiar with js and css you go further by investigating those topics:

https://www.drupal.org/node/304255
https://www.drupal.org/node/171209
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp